# Unity 3D movement sliding

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a FPS game but when I press w for a bit and then release it slides a bit further than wanted. I am pretty new to Unity and think it has something to do with the updates.
Code:

```
public float moveSpeed = 5f;
public float jumpForce = 5f;
public CharacterController controller;

private Vector3  moveDirection;
public float gravityScale;

void Start()
{
    controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
}

void Update()
{
    float yStore = moveDirection.y;

    moveDirection = (transform.forward * Input.GetAxis("Vertical")) + (transform.right * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"));
    moveDirection = moveDirection.normalized * moveSpeed;
    moveDirection.y = yStore;

    if (controller.isGrounded)
    {
        moveDirection.y = 0f;

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            moveDirection.y = jumpForce;
        }
    }

    moveDirection.y = moveDirection.y + (Physics.gravity.y * gravityScale);
    controller.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Comment: In general one problem might be in `moveDirection.normalized` .. this makes sure that even if the axis are e.g. `0.0001, 0.0001` it will still be normalized to a vector with magnitude `1` ... In general rarher use `ClampMagnitude` for this usecase

Comment: Well and then this uses a Rigidbody .. don't know exactly how that `CharacterController` works under the hood but maybe it doesn't stop the Rigidbody immediately

Answer (score 1):

add a physics material to your ground and set the dynamic friction to 1. Next, set the static friction from 0.5 to 1. And last but not least, set the bounciness to 0.

Play around with these values a bit until you find something that is satisfactory.
here is the link to the documentation:

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicMaterial.html

it basically explains what each property does.